# How to pull words based on positioning from a text element using Regex?

Tags: regex

I am looking for help to be able to (using REGEX) pull the the model from the text elements listed below.

- 2007 Honda CR-V LX CLEAN !!
- 2008 Honda Accord EX ROOF MAGS CLEAN 1 OWNER
- 2008 Honda Civic EX-L CUIR TOIT LEATHER
- 2009 Toyota Corolla S FULLY EQUIPPED

The constants factor is that,
The model is always the third word

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why don't you split the text by space? which language do you want to use?

Comment: I am using visual web ripper and am saving the file to XML. I really only can use REGEX to seperate the text element into the proper fields.

Comment: `^(\d{4})\s([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)` group 1 is for year, 2 is for make and 3 is for model.

Comment: Would you know how I would be able to pull only the model? (the third word on every line)  Thank you for all your help truly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would match with the regex `\d{4}` to get the first 4-digit number (the year) and then split it by spaces (with whichever language you are using) and then get the 2nd and 3rd words from that.

You could even just split it off spaces and use that, eg in Ruby:

```
array=my_name.split(" ")
year=array[0]
make=array[1]
model=array[2]
```

Basically I don't think regex would be the best solution here.

Comment: I don't have much of a choice but to use REGEX due to the software I am using. Thank you for the Regex to pull the year.  I am able to pull the make using Regex as well. The issue I am having is being able to pull the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex, it's

```
^(\d{4}) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +(.*)$
```

\1 is then the year, \2 the make, \3 the model, and \4 the rest. But this won't work if there are any models with two words (Crown Victoria, for example), unless you separate the words with something other than space (e.g. Crown_Victoria).

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one:

```
(\d+)\s*(\w+)\s*(.+)
```

and get groups.

explain:

```
\d+        digits (0-9) 
           (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

\s*        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") 
           (0 or  more times, matching the most amount possible)

\w+        word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) 
           (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

.+         any character except \n 
           (1 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link: [Regex Implementation](http://regexr.com?31m2e)

```
([0-9]*).\b([a-zA-z]*).\b([a-zA-z-.]*).\b(.*)
```

You will get 3 groups:

1. 2007
2. Honda
3. CR-V

**EDIT**

If you are using c# language then this would be the way to get `model`

```
string page = "2007 Honda CR-V LX CLEAN !!";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<year>[0-9]*).\b(?<make>[a-zA-z]*).\b(?<model>[a-zA-z-.]*).\b(?<rest>.*)");
MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(page);

foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Groups["model"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how I would be able to just pull the model using REGEX.